# Add Java Card Platform to NetBeans 18

Tags: javacard, netbeans-plugins

Does anybody know how to add a Java Card Platform to NetBeans 18. I tried to do it but the platform is somehow not getting recognized. Which file do I need to choose to add platform.

I downloaded the newest Java Card Platform. The Java Card plugins for NetBeans are also installed.

[[image]][image]

Comment: Hi guys, I could finally resolve this by myself! I found the location for Java Card Connected Platform, it was in C:\Users\....\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\18\JCDK3.0.2_ConnectedEdition. I added the platform manually.